# Close modal message box with JXA

Tags: macos, automation, javascript-automation

Writing JXA automation script that executes function of application.

```
var app = Application('Pages')
var doc = app.open(new Path('path to file'))
app.export(doc, {
        to: new Path('path to file'),
        as: dstFormat,
        withParameters: params
    })
```

app.export function sometimes trows error message box. When that message box is thrown script execution stops. How automatically close that message box?

Answer (score 0):

If the error results from a 'path not found' case, you could precede app.open with a defensive check:

```
// doesFileExist :: FilePath -> IO Bool
const doesFileExist = strPath => {
    const ref = Ref();
    return $.NSFileManager.defaultManager
        .fileExistsAtPathIsDirectory(
            $(strPath)
            .stringByStandardizingPath, ref
        ) && ref[0] !== 1;
};
```